# Is it possible to exclude specific values from being included in Solr facets?

Tags: solr

I'm using Solr facets to get the most common values for specific fields. It has occurred to me that (for business logic purposes) it would be preferable to exclude certain values. I cannot seem to find a way to do this, however.

I'm not looking to exclude the filter query, as seems to be commonly discussed.

If I'm getting the top 3 facets for a field, and seeing that "ValueA", "ValueB", and "ValueC", I'd like to say, essentially, "Get facets that aren't ValueB". So my facet instead returns data for "ValueA", "ValueC", and "ValueD".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [the `facet.excludeTerms` parameter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/faceting.html#Faceting-Thefacet.excludeTermsParameter). According to the source the format seems to be "term1,term2" to exclude those two terms.

The feature was introduced with Solr 6.5.

If you need the same feature before Solr 6.5 - if you need to supply the term to exclude separately for each query, you're going to have to do it in your controller / Solr interfacing code. If you want to do it for a single or multiple terms across the whole index for all queries, add a separate field and filter out those terms while indexing.

Comment: Now we're talking! I do have an up-to-dat Solr. Thanks, I think this is exactly right. However, my terms are actually numeric, and so it's throwing an error. I guess I'll make a string version of that field and try again.

Comment: Is there a JSON Facet API equivalent?
Is there an `includeTerm` equivalent?